# Is there any way to turn on autocomplete for the IBM Cloud Kubernetes Service Cli same as for kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes, autocomplete, ibm-cloud

I would like to be able to type

`ibmcloud ks` TAB

with the api giving me options to choose from, same as the kubectl autocomplete function.
I have seen this somewhere before but can't seem to find any documentation so maybe it was a tweak.

Anyone any solutions or said tweaks?
The official docs [IBM Kubernetes Service Documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-cli-plugin-kubernetes-service-cli)

Cheers (I'm using zsh on Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: Like [this](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli/reference/ibmcloud?topic=cli-shell-autocomplete#shell-autocomplete-linux)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's [link](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli/reference/ibmcloud?topic=cli-shell-autocomplete#shell-autocomplete-linux) to the official documentation you are looking for

**For Linux or macOS**

```
source /usr/local/ibmcloud/autocomplete/zsh_autocomplete
```

into `~/.zshrc`.

Once sourced, the output of

ibmcloud ks TAB will be

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Article's a bit old, but: https://medium.com/@dancberg/how-to-setup-an-awesome-shell-experience-for-ibm-cloud-kubernetes-service-285467ddd455
may help (he's specifically using zsh, iirc).

In particular, the ibmcloud plugin now does the merged kube context by default, so you may be able to skip directly to the section titled "Additional awesome shell tools"